# Is there modern scholarship on Sefer HaBris?

Tags: history, jewish-books, science, books-generally, modern-times

Have there been any studies, examinations, comparisons, discussions etc.  of **Sefer HaBris** in light of modern (~21st Century) science. I'm looking for elaboration on this book particularly within a sphere or Torah scholarship, as is the original work itself.

Comment: What is this book? Who wrote it? etc

Comment: Great question. I'll try to update, in the mean time: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9D#:~:text=%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9D%20%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%91%20%D7%A2%D7%9C,%2C%20%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%94%2C%20%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A2%2C%20%D7%95%D7%98%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%92%D7%99%D7%94. https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA_(%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A5)